# I set SO_RCVLOWAT (Receive Low Water Mark ) option on a UDP socket but it doesn't work

Tags: c, sockets

I am using C network programming to set the socket option `SO_RCVLOWAT` on a UDP socket. I succeeded as shown by the return value of `getsockopt()`. The problem: I can still receive any data sizes greater than zero.

Example: I set the socket option SO_RCVLOWAT value to 1024 byte on the client side and server sent 256 byte to the client. It can receive the 256 byte, but it actually shouldn't receive this message because the receive low water mark is 1024 byte.

Relevant code:

```
rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVLOWAT, (char *)&recvlowat, sizeof(recvlowat));
        if(rc < 0){
                VL_MISC_ERR(("Setting SO_RCVLOWAT option error, %s",strerror(errno)));
                return -1;
        }
```

`sd` : a valid file descriptor

Then I use `recvfrom`:

```
c = recvfrom(sd, databuf,  datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr_in *)&localSock, &addrlen);
```

Comment: Not sure if this option is applicable to datagram sockets.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't supposed to have that effect in UDP. `recvfrom()` receives one datagram at a time, period. If you want to receive more than one at a time, use `recvmsg()`.

Comment: @user1680544 Why? Something wrong with the answer I already gave?

Comment: I tried recvfrom() and recv() , but they already haven't been worked !!

Comment: I tried these simple client and server on Stream socket, also doesn't work     http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzab6%2Frzab6xconoserver.htm

Comment: @user1680544 I suggest you read my answer, instead of just asking me further questions. You don't give the slightest appearance of having done so. I had already told you why those functions you are now calling won't do what you want. So calling them was already a waste of time. I also told you what function to call to get what you want. Neither of those is it.

Comment: Thank you I tried it on TCP and works successfully,, BTW I am automation network programming tester, my test role to check if the option works properly with recvfrom with loading specific library

Comment: That'd be `recvmmsg` surely?